# update columns to be in a absolute numerical order

Tags: mysql, sql

What I have:

```
subject_id       courseid     position
----------- ---------- --------------------
1                    1           0
2                    1           1
3                    1          50
4                    2          55
5                    1          56
6                    2          58
```

there is a relative order in `position` column, and i want to make it in absolute order like this:

What I want :

```
subject_id          courseid       position
----------- ---------- --------------------
1                     1              0
2                     1              1
3                     1              2
4                     2              0
5                     1              3
6                     2              1
```

Basically, I want that in each course the positions of the subjects will start from zero and so on

Comment: *Storing* positions with no gaps is problematic if you have to deal with deletions and out of order insertions. Usually best to *synthesize* the no-gaps `position` from the gappy `position` at `SELECT` time using a `ROW_NUMBER()` expression. (And if you have to deal with out-of-order inserts, using `float` rather than `int` as the underlying data type brings certain benefits too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do this with variables:

```
set @rn := -1;
set @c := -1;

update t
    set position = (@rn := if(@c = courseid, @rn + 1,
                              if(@c := courseid, 0, 0)
                             )
                   ) 
    order by courseid, id;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , but i think i need to explain myself better-  i want to order the rows so that the "position" column will be sorted in relative order - for example , if now in courseid=2 the subject id's is 4,5 and there positions are 55,58 - it means that this course has 2 subjects in it and subjectid=4 will appear first and the  subjectid=5 will appear second - my question is how can i turn this 55,58 values the appropriate relative order so that the first position in this course will be 0 , and the secons will be 1

Comment: your query is awesome! but - some of the values in `position` column are correct - ( there is courses that the position value is 0 - and it is the first one , so that we don't need to change that) and from your query it seems like the assumption was that they all need to be change

Comment: @July . . . If you want to preserve the original position ordering, then use `order by courseid, position`.  Unfortunately, this query needs to update all rows to be sure that `@rn` and `@c` are set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *correlated* subquery :

```
update t
     set t.position = (select count(t1.courseid) 
                       from t t1 
                       where t1.courseid = t.courseid and t1.subject_id < t.subject_id
                      );
```

Comment: this query does not do the trick - the idea is to make the values in `position` column start from zero and so on accordingly to the order of the existing values for each courseid individually